# How do you represent a list in a CSV?

Tags: csv

What is the standard way to represent a list/array value in CSV? For example, given this source data in JSON:

```
[
  {
    'name': 'Harry',
    'subjects': ['math', 'english', 'history']
  }
]
```

My guess as to a CSV representation would be:

```
name,subjects
Harry,["math","english","history"]
```

However that doesn't get parsed correctly (with the standard Python CSV parser).

Answer (score 1):

One option, though this is almost always a hack and should be avoided unless truly necessary, is to choose a delimiter that you know will *never* show up in your data.  For example:

```
name,subject
Harry,math|english|history
```

Of course you will have to manually handle splitting this string and turning it back into a list.  Existing CSV parsers should not support this, *because this concept fundamentally does not make sense in CSV.*

And of course, this does not generalize well - what happens in the future when you need to store a 2D list, or a dict, or you realize you *do* need that delimiter character after all?

The root problem here is that CSV is a tabular format, whereas JSON is a hierarchical format.  Rather than trying to "squeeze" one format to fit into a fundamentally incompatible format, you should instead [normalize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your data into a tabular representation.  One example of how this could look:

```
name,subject
Harry,math
Harry,english
Harry,history
```